# Why does constructor take such a long time here?

Tags: coq

Consider the following code:

```
Inductive Even : nat -> Prop :=
| EO : Even O
| ESS : forall n, Even n -> Even (S (S n)).

Fixpoint is_even_prop (n : nat) : Prop :=
  match n with
  | O => True
  | S O => False
  | S (S n) => is_even_prop n
  end.

Theorem is_even_prop_correct : forall n, is_even_prop n -> Even n.
Admitted.

Example Even_5000 : Even 5000.
Proof.
  apply is_even_prop_correct.

  Time constructor. (* ~0.45 secs *)
  Undo.

  Time (constructor 1). (* ~0.25 secs *)
  Undo.

  (* The documentation for constructor says that "constructor 1"
     should be the same thing as doing this: *)
  Time (apply I). (* ~0 secs *)
  Undo.

  (* Apparently, if there's only one applicable constructor,
     reflexivity falls back on constructor and consequently
     takes as much time as that tactic: *)
  Time reflexivity. (* Around ~0.45 secs also *)
  Undo.

  (* If we manually reduce before calling constructor things are
     faster, if we use the right reduction strategy: *)
  Time (cbv; constructor). (* ~0 secs *)
  Undo.

  Time (cbn; constructor). (* ~0.5 secs *)
Qed.

Theorem is_even_prop_correct_fast : forall n, is_even_prop n = True -> Even n.
Admitted.

Example Even_5000_fast : Even 5000.
Proof.
  apply is_even_prop_correct_fast.

  (* Everything here is essentially 0 secs: *)
  Time constructor.
  Undo.
  Time reflexivity.
  Undo.
  Time (apply eq_refl). Qed.
```

I just wanted to see if you could do reflection in `Prop` rather than `Set` and stumbled upon this. My question is not how to do the reflection properly, I just want to know why `constructor` is so slow in the first case compared to the second case. (Maybe it has something to do with that `constructor` can immediately see (without any reductions) that the constructor must be `eq_refl` in the second case? But it must still reduce afterwards...)

Also, while trying to figure out what `constructor` is doing I noticed that the documentation does not say which reduction strategy will be used by the tactic. Is this omission intentional, and the idea is that you should explicitly say which reduction strategy you want if you want one in particular (otherwise the implementation is free to pick any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: It spends its time trying to figure out what inductive family your goal is a part of (twice, in the case of `constructor`), using `hnf`.

Longer answer: Doing a bit of source-diving, it looks like [`constructor` calls `Tactics.any_constructor`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/V8.7+beta1/plugins/ltac/coretactics.ml4#L118), while [`constructor 1` calls `Tactics.constructor_tac`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/V8.7+beta1/plugins/ltac/coretactics.ml4#L122-L124).  [`Tactics.any_constructor`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/V8.7+beta1/tactics/tactics.ml#L2212-L2225) in turn calls `Tacmach.New.pf_apply Tacred.reduce_to_quantified_ind` to determine the inductive type to count the constructors, and then calls `Tactics.constructor_tac` on each possible constructor in turn.  For `True`, since there is one constructor, it's suggestive that the time for `constructor` is about double the time for `constructor 1`; I'm guessing that the time is therefore spent in `reduce_to_quantified_ind`.  `Tacred.reduce_to_quantified_ind`, in turn, calls [`reduce_to_ind_gen`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/V8.7+beta1/pretyping/tacred.ml#L1191-L1210), which, in turn calls `hnf_constr`.  And, indeed, it looks like `Time hnf` and `Time constructor 1` are about the same.  Furthermore, `Time constructor` is instant after a manual `hnf`.  I'm not sure what strategy `hnf` uses internally.  The documentation omission is almost certainly not deliberate (at least, whatever the current strategy is should appear in a footnote, I think, so feel free to report a bug), but it's not clear to me that the reduction strategy used by `constructor` in determining what inductive family your goal is a part of should be part of the specification of `constructor`.

Comment: To clarify my `constructor`'s reduction strategy comment: I did not mean that the reduction strategy must be added to the documentation/specification; rather, I wanted to know if something is said (in the manual) about the strategies used in general. It could be the case that somewhere in the manual it is said that "if not stated otherwise, cbv will be used everywhere", "you cannot rely on any specific reduction strategy being used, instead, which strategy is used depends on implementation-details and is decided on a case-by-case-basis (sometimes dynamically)", or something like that.

Comment: ... Because it seems that sometimes this information would be useful (e.g., here), but at the same time being overly reliant on such low-level details probably results in very fragile proof scripts.